# Correlated variable not getting evaluated

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have created an regular expression to extract CSRF token from the HTTP Headers and storing the value in the reference name CSRF_TOKEN by following this [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)

I using this variable in POST Parameters of another HttpRequest as below

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=${CSRF_TOKEN}
```

Here ${CSRF_TOKEN} is not getting evaluated and the server is getting the middleware token as csrfmiddlewaretoken=%24%7BCSRF_TOKEN%7D

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show your regular expression extractor ?

Comment: in addition to @UBIK LOAD PACK requested, can you also please post the response which you are using to extract the value

Comment: Here is my regular expression after my fix: 

    Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=(.+?);

And the response headers are 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Cookie
Content-Length: 21901
Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=R03ysqEIIn0NVFjQchFjTxdXYfwl37AIFUyTO9lElMBishgu8ao0SoJqZlEoinXO; expires=Sat, 09-Nov-2019 21:18:33 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/

Answer (score 2):

It got resolved. I identified that, if the regular expression is not matching any value and there is no default value specified, then JMeter is not treating as a dynamic variable.  I corrected it by fixing regular expression. it starts working.  Thank you.